# JavaScript: JSON.stringify and replacer, Unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

Consider the following code

```
'use strict'; 

function stringify(value,p) {
    function replacer(k,v) {
        if (!Array.isArray(v))
            return p(k) ? v : undefined;
        return v
    }
    return JSON.stringify(value,replacer);
}

console.log(stringify([{ city: 'Milano', air_quality: 'red', temperature: 10 }, { air_quality: 'yellow', 'temperature': 20, 'sea_conditions': 3, city: 'Genova' }], k => k.match(/^[a-z]+$/)));
console.log(stringify([{ city: 'Milano', air_quality: 'red', temperature: 10 }, { air_quality: 'yellow', 'temperature': 20, 'sea_conditions': 3, city: 'Genova' }], k => k.length < 5));
```

i'm expecting the following output

```
[{"city":"Milano","temperature":10},{"temperature":20,"city":"Genova"}]
[{"city":"Milano"},{"city":"Genova"}]
```

but i'm obtaining

```
[null,null]
[{"city":"Milano"},{"city":"Genova"}]
```

so basically it works for the second input but not for the first one, and i absolutely can't explain why, the only thing that changes is the predicate used!

i know that with the following replacer

```
 function replacer(k,v){
        if (typeof v === 'object' && !Array.isArray(v)) {
            let result = {}
            for (let idx in v) {
                if(p(idx)) {
                    result[idx] = v[idx]
                }
            }
            return result
        }
        return v
    }
```

everything will work as expected, but can someone explain me why in the first version it worked on one input and not on the other?

Comment: Can you explain what it is exactly that you're trying to do?  I'm having a really hard time following why you're involving JSON stringify in normal data manipulation.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything other than understanding how things work.
It's just an introductory assignment for a university course.

Answer (score 2):

The keys in the outer array you pass to your `stringify()` function are 0 and 1. Neither of those match the regex (which looks for letters), so the values in the result are `null` (because `undefined` cannot be represented in JSON).

Comment: @1.1 When the key is `0` or `1` then `v` represents the associated object in your objects at that index (not your parent array), so `p` is still executed as `Array.isArray(v)` will be `false` for an object (which you negate). You can add `console.log(k, v);`) before the `if` to see and get a better idea.

Comment: @1.1 no, the *value* at each array key is *not* an array.